# How do I configure a qt creator project when I have no kits on my qt creator

Tags: macos, qt, qt-creator

[this is how my qt creator looks after opening a .pro file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtLvL.png)

how do I fix this?
I think I have deleted some settings files and also some make and build options. Please help me out here!!
I have MacBook Air M2 Silicon.

I tried adding new kits, but could not find my device.

Answer (score 0):

I think u can deleted and download again,but i not suggested.

Comment: I did that but it still it does not download the default kits again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).